# Why it shows "NameError: name 'histogram' is not defined"?

Tags: python, histogram

I'm taking a course on Coursera and doing an assignment after watching a teaching video.
[image]

[image]

I wanna know why it shows "NameError: name 'histogram' is not defined" after running my own code.

Comment: `histogram()` is not a built-in function, you need to define it.

Comment: How to define it? I know maybe it's a silly question but I never learned Python so don't know how to do that?

Comment: The video probably included the definition earlier.

Comment: Oh actually no.

Comment: Or maybe it's in a library that you're supposed to download. I would expect the course to explain how to get the definition.

Comment: There's a `histogram()` function in the `numpy` library. `from numpy import histogram`

Comment: May u help give me the code. I'd like to write by myself but I have no any concept of Python.

Comment: I haven't watched the video, I have no idea what histogram function they're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add histogram library in your code. please add line in the starting of the code. I should work properly.

```
from histograms import histograms
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to import the Histogram function as it is not built into Python. There are a few different packages that offer histograms -- for example pyplot and numpy. Here's an example using numpy

```
import numpy as np

np.histogram([1, 2])
```

Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html